# Can "during" modify a noun?

Tags: prepositions

> Penalty for drivers is determined on the basis of the maximum speed
>   during driving.

Could you advise me on whether the above is grammatically correct.

I think this example is not good, but I would just like to know whether "during" can modify the noun "maximum speed" in front of it or some verb such as "appearing" is required in front of it.

Comment: I think _while_ would be better than _during_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- With a **"participle"** or **"gerund"** avoid using "**during**" and use "**while**" instead. ([Longman Dictionary](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/during))

> Don’t say ‘during doing something’ or ‘during someone does something’.
>   Use while: They chatted while waiting for the train (NOT during
>   waiting for the train). | He stole her money while she slept (NOT
>   during she slept).

- **During** is mostly followed by a **noun** but sometimes by an **article + gerund**.
- Try to avoid two **-ing** words in a row no matter how they occur in a sentence.

---

So the correct sentence is: **"Penalty for drivers is determined on the basis of the maximum speed while driving."**

Compare:

1. During my stay at the hotel, several interesting events took place.
2. While I stayed at the hotel, several interesting events took place.

Comment: You don't need to say "during my staying". Yoy just need to say "during my say". There's a bunch of verbs that has a noun meaning without any need for a suffix/removal of a suffix.

Comment: @iBug Yeh, you're right! Gotta correct that.